# How can I add multiple numbers to a variable

Tags: c++, variables, variable-assignment, compound-assignment

I'm trying to use `+=` to add multiple numbers to a variable.

I'm trying to do something like this:
`score += var1, var2, var3`

However, the only thing I know how to do now is

```
score += p;
score += v;
score += t;
```

Comment: Is score something other than a primitive type - like float, int, string, etc..?

Comment: [Comma has interesting behaviour.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)  The outcome of `score += var1, var2, var3` surprised me until I thought about precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
score += var1 + var2 + var3;
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression statement

```
score += var1, var2, var3;
```

is a statement with the comma operator expression.

It is equivalent to

```
( score += var1 ), ( var2 ), ( var3 );
```

So the variable `score` will be incremented only by `var1`.

You could write instead

```
score += var1 + var2 + var3;
```

But if you have many variables or values that you need to add to the variable `score` then you can use an initializer list as for example

```
for ( const auto &item : { var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 } )
{
    score += item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@cigen's answer is perfect, but lets break the math and programming:

In math:

```
A = A + B + C
```

is same as

```
A = A + (B + C)
```

Now comes the programming part:

```
A = A + <something>
```

is the same as

```
A += <something>
```

this we can have

```
<something> = B + C
```

and when combined

```
A += B + C
```